# Homebrew link python to /usr/local/bin/ on Mac

Tags: python, bash, macos, homebrew

I would like to ask how to install python on Mac through Homebrew. 
Homebrew is a package manager for Mac.

Specifically I would like to link python to `/usr/local/bin/` and not to `/usr/bin/` where it is linked by default.

The reason to do this is that I want then to install a virtual environment which will provide me the libraries of python (see: https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-macos/). Otherwise the virtual environment cannot be installed as `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` in the `bash_profile` cannot be read.

Do you have any idea how can I do this?

**In brief, I want the output to `which python` at terminal to be `/usr/local/bin/python` and not `/usr/bin/python` as it is by default.**

***UPDATE***:
I applied the changes that TomD described below (I hope correctly!) but now `which python` has not output: is not `/usr/local/bin/python` as I would like (not even `/usr/bin/python`).
**So why finally python from 'cellar' is not linked to `/usr/local/bin/python`?**

Comment: is there a specific reason for the directory change?  For example are you looking for it to overwrite the systems version of python?

Comment: Thanks for you interest. I modified my body text to respond to this. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: By default, the homebrew install of Python should already be placing the binaries into `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Hhmm...I am not so sure about it. When I type 'which python' the answer is /usr/bin/python and this is my problem. It should be /usr/local/bin/python so that I can install my virtual environment etc.

Comment: That sounds more like a `PATH` environment variable problem, with `/usr/bin` coming before `/usr/local/bin`. If the path is correct, does `ls /usr/local/bin/python` return anything?

Comment: It returns 'ls: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory' because exactly python is in /usr/bin (if I am right). But I want to have it (or to create a symlink) to /usr/local/bin/ for it. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Just to give a few basics first.  Homebrew installs everything in the "cellar".  That's where the "kegs" (packages) go.

Homebrew then creates symlinks to their files into /usr/local/.

For example, python is installed in /usr/local/Cellar/python

So I would suggest after installation, remove the symlink to /usr/bin and make one to /usr/local/bin.

remove symlink:

```
unlink /usr/bin/python
```

make symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python /usr/bin/python
```

also make sure that your $PATH is correct and /usr/local/bin is before usr/bin

Comment: Thank you for answer but in a sense this is my principal question: 'HOW TO remove the symlink to /usr/bin and make one to /usr/local/bin'? I would appreciate a more detailed answer.

Comment: also make sure that your $PATH is correct and /usr/local/bin is before usr/bin

Comment: Yes, /usr/local/bin is before usr/bin and I type 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' at the 'bash_profile' (as the link says) so I think that all these are ok. So 'HOW TO remove the symlink to /usr/bin and make one to /usr/local/bin' again please?

Comment: modified my answer to include how to remove and create symlinks

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give it a try. (By the way, I wonder why this author at the link presupposes that the output of  'which python' would be /usr/local/bin/ and not /usr/bin/ without even referring to symlinks etc)

Comment: So in the first case I get the response 'unlink: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted' and in the second case I get the response 'ln: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted'. Why is this?

Comment: try to create the symlink with sudo.  It seems you are having a permission issue.  Also, if you need to change your $PATH.. make sure you open a new terminal after doing it.

Comment: Alright. I think that I did it but now which python gives no output now (see my edited post above). Why is this?

Comment: Also what do you mean very specifically by setting the path properly? (I am struggling with all this for hours...almost for a day!?!...haha)

Comment: your env var $PATH.  make sure the linked directory you want to use is first in the list of directories

Comment: I have written 'export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH' at my bash_profile and when I open '/etc/paths/' then '/usr/local/bin' is higher than 'usr/bin'. So why 'which python' does not give any output after implementing your suggestions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159166/discussion-between-poetemaudit-and-tomd).